# how to disable routerLink For an Inner Element

Tags: angular

hello guys i have a problem with `routerLink` i gave it to a `li` but i don't want it to work for an inner Element of `li` my HTML is like this:

```
     <li class="list-item bg-list-item padding-x" [ngClass]="selected && index == 2 ? 'list-grow' : ''" routerLink="/task">
        <input type="checkbox" id="item2">
        <h1 id="self">
          Board Name
          <label for="item2"><i class="icon gray right-align icon-Edit large" (click)="rename(2)"></i></label>
        </h1>
        <h1 id="edit">
          <input type="text" placeholder="rename board name">
          <label for="item2"><i class="icon gray right-align icon-OK large" (click)="rename(0)"></i></label>
        </h1>
        <h4 class="free-space-top-x gray">Last Modified by Alfred</h4>
        <ul class="free-space-top-2x horizontal-list">
          <li class=""><i class="icon gray icon-Tasks-List medium"></i>10</li>
          <li class=""><i class="icon gray icon-Employees-Count medium"></i> 3</li>
          <li class=""><i class="icon gray icon-Comment medium"></i>+99</li>
          <li class=""><i class="icon gray icon-Bell medium"></i>9</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
```

and i don't want `routerLink` work for labels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add this to your `click` event:

```
(click)="$event.stopPropagation(); rename(0);"
```

Comment: tnx it worked..

Answer (score 1):

change

```
(click)="rename(2)"
```

to

```
(click)="rename(2, $event)"
```

and rename source to :-

```
rename(id, event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  //remaining code
}
```

Comment: already tried this didn't work i guess router called faster than rename function